# PHP script to write to new file using variables from HTML form

Tags: php

I have the following script which is working well at taking the data from my HTML form and writing it to a .conf file.

```
<?php
 $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/phptest.conf';
 if (isset($_POST['CollectorIP']) && isset($_POST['CollectorPort']) && isset($_POST['NetflowVersion'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = 'collector-ip='.$_POST['CollectorIP']. "\n". 'collector-port='.$_POST['CollectorPort']. "\n". 'engine='.$_POST['NetflowVersion'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
?>
```

However I am needing this script to "auto-name" the .conf files differently using the variables from the HTML form. For example, at the moment the script is creating the file `phptest.conf` and writing the below info (which will be different each time) which was inputted via the HTML form:

```
collector-ip=10.0.0.0
collector-port=9000
engine=Netflow Version 10 (IPFIX)
```

As these three inputs will be unique every time the script is run I would like to use them to name the new file each time the form is submitted.

For example if the collector-ip was 5.5.5.5, collector-port 9996 and engine Netflow Version 10 (IPFIX) the filename would be `5.5.5.5:9996:Netflow Version 10 (IPFIX).conf`.

I am quite new to PHP but I believe this could be achieved by using the `(isset($_POST['CollectorIP'])`, `($_POST['CollectorPort'])` and `isset($_POST['NetflowVersion'])` variables in the file path which would complete from the inputted data and name the files as expected each time the form is submitted.

Is this correct or do I have it wrong? Would the following script work or is there a better way to do this?

```
<?php
 $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/(isset($_POST['CollectorIP']):isset($_POST['CollectorPort']):isset($_POST['NetflowVersion']).conf';
 if (isset($_POST['CollectorIP']) && isset($_POST['CollectorPort']) && isset($_POST['NetflowVersion'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = 'collector-ip='.$_POST['CollectorIP']. "\n". 'collector-port='.$_POST['CollectorPort']. "\n". 'engine='.$_POST['NetflowVersion'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
?>
```

**Update**

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) && isset($_POST['CollectorPort']) && isset($_POST['NetflowVersion']) && isset($_POST['Flowrate']) && isset($_POST['TemplateFrequency']) && isset($_POST['SourceIPAddress']) && isset($_POST['DestinationIPAddress']) ) {
    // ok let's try to create the file
    $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/' . trim($_POST['CollectorIP']) . ':' . trim($_POST['CollectorPort']) . ':' . trim($_POST['NetflowVersion']) . '.conf';
    $contents = "";
    if ( $fh = fopen($path,"a+") ) {
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= 'collector-ip=' . $_POST['CollectorIP'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'collector-port=' . $_POST['CollectorPort'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['NetflowVersion'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'engine=' . $_POST['NetflowVersion'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['Flowrate'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'flow-rate=' . $_POST['Flowrate'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['TemplateFrequency'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'template-freq=' . $_POST['TemplateFrequency'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['SourceIPAddress'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'src-ip=' . $_POST['SourceIPAddress'];
        }
          if ( trim( $_POST['DestinationIPAddress'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'dst-ip=' . $_POST['DestinationIPAddress'];
        }
        if ( fwrite( $fh, $contents ) ) {
        }
        fclose($fh); // Close the file
    }
else {
    if (fclose($fh)) {
        echo "Netflow traffic is now being sent to the collector at ". ( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ). " on port ". ( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ). ".";
    } else { 
        echo "The simulator was unable to start the traffic flow, please try again.";
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you intend to link these different files to the code that will use them?

Comment: ___Big LOGIC Note___ You use the $_POST occurances to build a path BEFORE you check if they actually exist

Comment: If you're just writing a single string to the file, use `file_put_contents()` instead of `fopen/fwrite/fclose`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before showing the code I think there are a couple of things worth pointing out:

1. it looks like you're receiving this data via a post on a web form. Therefore, your intention is to allow users to send data that will be written to a file on your server. This is a big security risk, so you'll want to be 100% certain that whatever they're entering is trustworthy.
2. Assuming the above is correct and this script will live on a web server, most of the time the script will not have write access to create a file / write to a file. So you'll have to modify permissions etc, which again has security concerns that you'll have to be aware of

Anyway, as far as the script itself, the line where you're using `isset` won't work as it's written. I would separate the test out and do it like so:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) && isset($_POST['CollectorPort']) && isset($_POST['NetflowVersion']) ) {
    // ok let's try to create the file
    $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/' . trim($_POST['CollectorIP']) . ':' . trim($_POST['CollectorPort']) . ':' . trim($_POST['NetflowVersion']) . '.conf';
    $contents = "";
    if ( $fh = fopen($path,"a+") ) {
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorIP'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= 'collector-ip=' . $_POST['CollectorIP'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['CollectorPort'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'collector-port=' . $_POST['CollectorPort'];
        }
        if ( trim( $_POST['NetflowVersion'] ) != "" ) {
            $contents .= "\n" . 'engine=' . $_POST['NetflowVersion']
        }
        if ( fwrite( $fh, $contents ) ) {
            // yay
        } else {
            // do some sort of error handling because the file couldn't be written to
        }
        fclose($fh); // Close the file
    } else {
        // do some sort of error handling because the file couldn't be opened
    }
} else {
    // do some sort of error handling because they didn't provide the necessary data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes I understand the security concerns, this is an internal tool I am building which is only going to create limited config files spun up by a backend engine.

I tried your modified script and it works perfectly, thanks again!

Comment: no problem, glad to hear it!

Comment: One thing I am having an issue with here is that the HTML form may on some occasions have some fields which are not populated on submission (as they are not required) but sometimes might be completed. How can I modify the PHP script here to stop it from writing these fields to the .conf file if they are not completed but write them if they are? 

@Mike Willis Don't suppose you could point me in the right direction or help me out with this at all? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Davearoo32, check out my edit to the original script. I set it to check each entry in the array to see if it's filled with something other than spaces by using the `trim()` function, and only write that entry to the file if so. I also changed the variable name from `$string` which isn't very descriptive, to `$contents`, but that's not all that important. Note that `$contents` defaults to an empty string, and it's possible for you to write a blank file if all 3 entries in the POST array are empty

Comment: I just tested the script and it works perfectly, thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: I don't suppose you could sanity check my latest edit by any chance? I am trying to echo a success or fail message depending if the file was created successfully. If it was created successfully I would like the message to be `Netflow traffic is now being sent to the collector at "collector IP specified" on port "collector port specified".`

Are my edits correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was missing a closing `)` on the `if` line

Comment: just saw this, glad you got it working!

Comment: Thanks @MikeWillis, although I am still having some trouble with the script (I have updated my question with the latest version I am using). As far as I can see my echo messages are correct however they don't seem to return when I run the script from the HTML form. I know the script runs because the .conf file is created as expected. 

Any idea what I might have wrong?

Comment: @Davearoo32 hmm that's really weird.. Just glancing at the updated code, it looks fine to me, and if the files are being created that rules out any syntax errors. Your web form is posting directly to this script? Do you see any other output? Could the `echo` statements be getting suppressed by an output buffer (`ob_start()`) or something similar?

Comment: @Davearoo32 scratch that, I looked at this in VSCode and I see some issues. The `echo` statements are set to run *only* if the `fopen` fails. If you're seeing the file get created, then the `fopen` is not failing, so it makes sense that you're not seeing the `echo` statements. What text editor are you using? Try opening this in something like VSCode or Notepad++ and make sure all the formatting / indenting is lined up perfectly. Then you should more easily be able to see that the `echo` parts are on the `else` of the `fopen`. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Thanks for taking a look I really appreciate it! I have updated my question with revised versions of the echo messages. Would you mind just sanity checking them for me, would these work correctly as success and fail messages? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Davearoo32, not quite - they're still only running if the `fopen()` fails, which I'm not sure if that's what you want. Notice you have two `fclose()` statements. The first one is correct and will run only if the `fopen()` succeeds. I think that's where you want your `echo` statements. The second `fclose()` will only run if the `fopen()` fails, so it won't really have anything to close since nothing was ever opened, and the `echo` statements will be misleading

Comment: Thanks @MikeWillis. I managed to get this sorted. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

Expressions aren't evaluated inside string literals. You need to use concatenation.

```
 $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/' . (isset($_POST['CollectorIP']):isset($_POST['CollectorPort']):isset($_POST['NetflowVersion']) . '.conf';
```

You should be very careful when using POST data in filenames, since the user could put `../../..` in the value to access outside the directory you want to write to. Add some data validation, or use `basename()` to discard the directory part.

Comment: String are correctly escaped, he even uses double quote to concatenate EOL. Your code is not related to the issue, which is about the file content and not its path

Comment: No it isn't. 1. Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes. 2. If the variable is an array with quotes around the index, you need to put `{}` around it. 3. You can't call functions like `isset()` or use operators like `?:`.